# Where to find negative image dataset for Haar Cascade

Tags: data-request, images

Where can I get an image dataset with negative images for using with a [Haar Cascade](http://www.willberger.org/cascade-haar-explained/) algorithm for image detection?

I would like to make an application to detect the basketball basket.

Comment: There are plenty of datasets with ordinary 'positive' images. Why don't you use those and negate them yourself?

Answer (score 0):

This dataset from [Kaggle contains Negative Images](https://www.kaggle.com/muhammadkhalid/negative-images) which you can use it for haar cascade or other machine learning / deep learning algorithms.

---

[Haar cascade negative sample images](https://github.com/JoakimSoderberg/haarcascade-negatives)